# Downgrade Xcode project compatibility to Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

While I was developing my iPhone app, Xcode 5 beta came out, so I decided to try it out. I finished coding my app using Xcode DP-2, and now I want to submit it to the App Store. However, this message appears when validating my app through the Xcode Organizer:

[image: Xcode Organizer error message]

Is there a way I can change my project settings so I can recompile it using Xcode 4.6.x, and upload it to iTunes Connect correctly?

Comment: Have you tried just opening it in 4.6 and compiling?

Comment: Let this be a lesson to you.  I guess you missed all the big print saying that you can't submit applications using the developer preview.  Even without knowing that it should be obvious, but that's beside the point.  There really isn't much that I can get into specifically because of the NDK, but usually new versions of Xcode will introduce new parameters into XIB files, so make sure that you've set your XIB compatibility to Xcode 4.6.  After that just try what Undo says.  If that doesn't work then I hope you used SVN or Git, etc.

Comment: @borrrden - "Let this be a lesson to you" lol spoke like a true teacher.

Comment: @borrrden Lesson learnt. Thanks. At this point in time I have successfully been able to build the app using 4.6, thanks to all.